# Efficient ways to search a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my first time posting here.  I'm new to programming and I have a question, but I'm not sure how much information I need to include in order to get good advice so if I'm too vague please let me know.

I'm working on writing a dynamic programming algorithm to solve a vehicle routing problem with time windows using a bottom up approach.  As I generate partial solutions to the problem I am storing them in a dictionary with the key `(tuple(jobs_served), tuple(current_vehicle_location), tuple(current_vehicle_times))` with the values `(tuple(current_cost), tuple(previous_vehicle_location), tuple(previous_vehicle_time), tuple(current_vehicle_order))`.

Before adding any partial solution to my dictionary (which I call self.memo) I perform a number of tests to eliminate infeasible solutions, dominated solutions, or skipping any repeated configurations.  To do some or these checks (repeated configuration and dominance) I am searching the dictionary to see if I've already added a partial configuration.  I am keeping these partial solutions in a separate dictionary because they are used by a number of other functions.  I generate the dictionary of partial solutions by:

```
self.label_check = {k: v for k, v in self.memo.items() if k[0]==self.new_visited and k[1]==self.sorted_nlp}
```

And then I search that dictionary for a specific key using:

```
dup_label_check = {k: v for k, v in self.label_check.items() if k[0]==self.new_visited and k[1]==self.sorted_nlp and k[2]==self.sorted_nt}
```

And this all works fine.  But when I run the performance profiler I find I'm spending over 50% of my time doing dictionary functions.  I suspect that the searches I've listed above are the culprit as they're called thousands of times.  I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of looking up these labels?

Comment: Note you can do `dup_label_check = {k: v for k, v in self.label_check.items() if k[:3]==[self.new_visited, self.sorted_nlp, self.sorted_nt]}` instead.

Comment: Perhaps you could store a separate `dict` or `set` of the partial solutions, and perform checks on that? Something like `(self.new_visited, self.sorted_nlp, self.sorted_nt) in self.partial_matches` should be a lot faster.

Comment: @AnnZen will this change the performance of the search or is this just a stylistic change?

Comment: @Peter I can make this change for the duplicate label check and this is an improvement.  Thank You! 
 However, for the dominance check I need to compare the current times and costs with the times and costs with everything in the self.label_check dictionary.  So I still need to construct that dictionary ...

Comment: @AnthonyKulick It's more clean and pythonic.